# Mongoose.create + Q convert mongoose promises into Q promises

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, q

I'm trying to use mongoose promises with Q.

What I would like to see is:

```
var promise1 = Model.create({
    field: 'value1'
});
var promise2 = Model.create({
    field: 'value2'
});

Q.all([promise1, promise2], function(){
    console.log("promises resolved");
});
```

)

Of course it doesn't work. I miss something to wrap mongoose promises in the Q promise objects. Is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: Will Q coerce the mongoose promises individually - `promise1 = Q(promise1);` and `promise2 = Q(promise2);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't pass the 'resolved' callback to the call to `all`, you call `done` on the returned promise and pass the callback to that:

This worked fine when I tried it:

```
Q.all([promise1, promise2]).done(function(docs){
    console.log("promises resolved");
});
```